# Does React Native perform Tree Shaking?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to weigh up the benefits of converting `moment` to `date-fns`.

Moment is currently `316k` or `67.6k` gzipped.

`date-fns/format` is `3k`.

We deliver updates through CodePush so minimising the JavaScript bundle is something that we need to definitely think about doing.

Does React-Native perform Tree Shaking?

Answer (score 13):

react-native or more specifically, the metro-bundler that comes with react-native by default doesn't support tree-shaking.

Tree-shaking issue was closed. You could find their motivation [here](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/227#issuecomment-583358386).

Comment: One option you may want to consider is doing react-native with multiple bundles, and only code-push the bundles you want? (Not sure if code push supports this, however!)

Comment: According to that issue in github, they have killed this feature.

Answer (score 1):

There is a toolset [rnx-kit](https://microsoft.github.io/rnx-kit/docs/introduction) that enhances Metro bundler with some useful features like symlinks, type-safe bundling, tree shaking, etc.

Here is some [config](https://microsoft.github.io/rnx-kit/docs/guides/bundling#tree-shaking) to enable tree shaking for your RN app.

PS: For a small project, tree shaking has almost zero sense :-)

Comment: Can you briefly explain the solution and provide a relevant code snippet, if possible?