# Problems using "index.js" to import ES6 JS Modules

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-modules

I'm working with *React Native* and using **index.js** to manage modules. I have many projects consuming from the same components folder, which has a structure like this:

```
components
|_ComponentOne.js
|_ComponentTwo.js
|_index.js
```

In which the index.js looks like this:

```
export * from './ComponentOne.js';
export * from './ComponentTwo.js';
```

---

Now lets say I have three projects:

- **ProjectOne**, which uses ComponentOne;
- **ProjectTwo**, which uses ComponentTwo;
- **ProjectThree**, which uses both;

Every project has its own files, but they refer to this same folder to use components (like a shared assets folder). Everything works fine while all the projects have all dependencies for all components.

In another words, I have a problem when one of the projects doesn't install a dependency for one of the components, **even when the project doesn't uses that component**.

Let's take as an example **ProjectOne**, which uses only **ComponentOne**. If **ComponentTwo** (which is not used in this project) has dependency X, I have to *npm install* dependency X even on **ProjectOne**, or an error is given. Again, **ProjectOne** doesn't use dependency X.

I can only image this happens because the *index.js* validates all declared exports, even when they're not used.

I'm trying to find an alternative to not be forced to install plugins and other things that I won't even use in my projects. I know that if I remove the *index.js* and start importing files directly on projects, it will work, but I would like to keep the *index.js* structure (to be able to use multi import syntax `import { ComponentOne, ComponentTwo } from 'components'`).

Any suggestion?

---

**Update:**

The error I get, when I **do not** *npm install dependency X* is

`` Module `X` does not exist in the Haste module map ``

If I install it, everything works.

I'm using the terminal to install the application directly into an android phone. The JS bundle is automatically created by Metro (RN default).

Comment: *"I can only image this happens because the index.js validates all declared exports, even when they're not used."* Nope, that's not how ES2015 modules (ESM) work. If `index.js` includes only `ComponentOne.js`, nothing is going to magically make it depend on `ComponentTwo.js` (and thus to dependency X). Something *else* is doing that (your bundler or similar), not ESM. Please update your question with the details of **exactly** what error you're getting, from what tool(s), and what your environment is (browser, Node.js, ...).

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/227 found via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272240/does-react-native-perform-tree-shaking

Comment: @t.j. "React Native" is actually all we need ... ;)

Comment: "*I can only image this happens because the index.js validates all declared exports, even when they're not used.*" - yes, when `index.js` imports (or exports from) both components, then importing the index.js file will load all the imported components, no matter whether they are used or not. Sounds like you really want two distinct packages with different npm dependencies. The alternative would be some kind of build switch.

Comment: @ mauricio - Are you saying you have an `index.js` with `import { One, Two } from 'components'` in it in a project that doesn't use component `Two`? If so, then of course that means you need to install `Two`'s dependencies. To avoid that, use a different `index.js` that *doesn't* reference `Two`, since you don't use it. In my comment above, I assumed you had a different `index.js` that didn't reference `Two` in the project that doesn't use it.

Comment: I have an index.js with

`export * from './ComponentOne.js';export * from './ComponentTwo.js';`

and on project one I only do `import { ComponentOne } from 'components';`