# Is APK size affected by unused packages in ReactNative?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to know do unused packages cause `APK` size to grow?

Consider I install dozens of `NPM` packages for my project but I never import and use them. These files obviously increase my project folder size but do they affect `APK` size when building `APK`?

The question can be answered about `.ipa` too.

Comment: Use the APK analyzer to check it yourself https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does React Native perform Tree Shaking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272240/does-react-native-perform-tree-shaking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APK Analyzer will not look for any unused dependent NPM packages because all your javascript code is bundled by metro before being included in your Android project as an index.android.bundle asset:

> Metro is a JavaScript bundler. It takes in an entry file and various options, and gives you back a single JavaScript file that includes all your code and its dependencies.

So any unused dependencies must be pruned before creating the apk. Read about [Tree shaking](https://medium.com/@FloSloot/tree-shaking-lets-implement-it-8de1c29f49e9), which does exactly that:

> Tree shaking is a process in which the bundler includes only the code that is actually used.

Note that only modules that have a dependency from your code will be included in the bundle.